# Updatepanel controller display issues

Tags: css, asp.net-ajax

Im trying to create a popup using a asp.net updatepanel. I want the background of the popup to fill the whole page (100% width, 100% height) and have the width of the popup itself set to 1000px and positioned top center.

I've tried wrapping the panel in a div and setting the width to 100%. However the browser simply ignores it. How can I control an asp.net update panel using css? and can the above be achieved?

the html:

```
<!-- Group Details Popup Starts  -->
<div id="divGroupDetails" runat="server">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="groupDetailsPopup" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <div class="popup_wrapper">

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbcloseBTN" runat="server">Close</asp:LinkButton>
                    matt
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

</div>
```

the css:

```
    .popup_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background-color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: absolute;` to your css. Or, in practice, you might find this more robust:

```
.popup_wrapper {
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modalpopup extender of ajax control toolkit and use following css :

```
    .ModalPopupBG
    {
        background-color: #666699;
        filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

HTML Source:

```
    <td> 
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
       <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MyPopup" runat="server" 
                DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                TargetControlID="HiddenField1" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </td>

    <td>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <table class="style1" bgcolor="#CC99FF">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style13">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="style17">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="style7">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style18">
                            Enter Name</td>
                        <td align="left" class="style19">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="style20">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style10">
                        </td>
                        <td class="style16">
                        </td>
                        <td class="style12">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style13">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left" class="style17">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button2_Click" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="style7">
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
   </td>
```

In code open popup

```
      popup.show();
```